# MariaDB - Can I manually add id's to SELECT FROM()?

Tags: sql, select, mariadb

This is the simplified query, and I would like to add the id's manually inside the `FROM ()`, I tried several ways but looks not possible.

```
SELECT p._data FROM (
  SELECT p_id FROM p WHERE search=? LIMIT 10
)s JOIN p ON p.p_id = s.p_id
```

I would like to do something like this, but that works:

```
FROM (SELECT [1,2,3,4,5,6] AS p_id)s
```

> 'I know I can use IN() but is much restrictive.' === false

PD: I' using 10.1.29-MariaDB. Apparently before there was JSON_ARRAY(),that could have worked, but not anymore.
PD2: Oh it's back again with 10.2.3, I might upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION ALL` (or `UNION` if you don't want there to be any possible duplicates):

```
SELECT p._data 
FROM (SELECT 1 AS p_id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) s
JOIN p ON p.p_id = s.p_id
```

As @RickJames points out, from MariaDB 10.1 onwards, you can use the [sequence engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/) to generate a list of numbers:

```
SELECT p.p_id, p._data
FROM seq_1_to_6 s
JOIN p ON p.p_id = s.seq
```

[Simple demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=04ff23d2114b6c025b96e210cfd0aed0)

Comment: I know but I might add up to ~500. I did a little test and looks like it could get a little slow, not as slow as the real query obviously (half) but maybe not the best option for a big array.

Comment: @Vixxs the optimal way would be with an `IN`. Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: Oh my bad, I was not using it because I need LIMIT... and I thought it was slower, but not if I add the id's manually... I was not thinking straight

Comment: @Nick . . . You should use `UNION ALL` by default, unless you specifically want the database to incur overhead for removing duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good point, I had assumed that in a situation like this (`UNION` of constant values) it would be smart enough to realise there weren't any, but I guess even that requires some processing. I'll edit...

Comment: @Nick . . . I am not aware of any database that implements that optimization -- although I would be happy to hear about that.  In general, database optimizers do not focus on "poorly written" (not a great choice of words) code but on underlying algorithms.  I'm don't mean to imply that `union` is actually poorly written, merely that there is an easy, documented way to express the intent of the code.

Comment: With some cross joins, you can easily generate a 'table' with thousands of _consecutive_ numbers.

Comment: Before version 10.1 / 5.7, MariaDB/MySQL would always create a temp table when doing any `UNION`.  After that _certain_ `UNION ALL` queries could avoid the temp.  Note `UNION DISTINCT` is the default when you say just `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

Really simple in MariaDB.  Use this pseudo-table:

```
seq_1_to_6
```

See the [*documentation*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/)
 for variants on that.  (Note:  Two things in MariaDB share the term "sequence".)

Comment: Very cool! I didn't know about that feature. I hope you don't mind but I've expanded it into the required query in my answer.

Comment: @Nick - make it even better -- Just `JOIN` to the sequence; don't bother with a subquery.

Comment: You are of course right, I was fussing with making the variable name `p_id` but there's no reason not to use the given one of `seq`